# Why does this map declaration throw a type error?

Tags: typescript, maps

I tried declaring a variable where each key in the map is an array of objects. for some reason the act of making the value an array throws a type error.

this is allowed:

```
var map = new Map([
            ['a', {c: 1}],
            ['b', {c: 1, d: 1}]
        ])
```

this is not allowed:

```
var map = new Map([
            ['a', [{c: 1}]],
            ['b', [{c: 1, d: 1}]]
        ])
```

the second piece of code will throw this error:
Type '{ a: number; b: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; }'

why is the first piece of code allowed but the second not allowed? i would expect to be allowed to have different types on each key of my map

Comment: [They both seem to work in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/G4QwTgBAtiAOCMEC8EB2BTA7hAsnAFANoBQEZ5FZhA5CNQDQQDeAxgFwTwC+AuvaZUE0ARg2btOjACYduPYjwCUxYqEgxYAJmRosuAiUFDaYwq1m8+Ao+RGnzkiDM6WFy4kA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your types are't consistent. You can explicitly tell Map the types it's going to have

```
interface MapValue {
  c: number;
  d?: number;
}

const map = new Map<string, MapValue[]>([
  ['a', [{ c: 1 }]],
  ['b', [{ c: 1, d: 1 }]]
])

// or

interface MapValue {
  c: number;
  d: number;
}

const map = new Map<string, MapValue[]>([
  ['a', [{ c: 1 } as MapValue]],
  ['b', [{ c: 1, d: 1}]]
```